# laravel Auth::user() null > session file not there

Tags: laravel, authentication, session

I know that several users had this problem but no solution offered seemed to help me.

I made a debug log tracking the flow and data:

1. Login
2. After the Login RedirectIfAuthenticated: correct userData and
   role
3. LoginController shows also correct Data > redirects to /admin
4. Again RedirectIfAuthenticated BUT THIS TIME ALL DATA ARE EMPTY

My session tracking is set to file
Here is my log but I have no clue what happens to the session token or why the request suddenly looses its data... I have the impression that there is an issue with the session, as I cannot find the tokenString in any newer sessionfile

```
[2019-08-02 00:25:37] production.DEBUG: RedirectIfAuthenticated handle  
[2019-08-02 00:25:37] production.DEBUG: Request array (
  '_token' => 'RNIq0gqNNYIbTshxh9S0f1Jrhowsihap8QzZioJ8',
  'email' => 'xxx',
  'password' => 'xxx',
  'remember' => 'on',
)  
[2019-08-02 00:25:37] production.DEBUG:   
[2019-08-02 00:25:38] production.DEBUG: LoginCOntroller ROLE_ADMIN  
[2019-08-02 00:25:38] production.DEBUG: ok, we have a Role (admin) here goto /admin  
[2019-08-02 00:25:38] production.DEBUG: Request array (
  '_token' => 'RNIq0gqNNYIbTshxh9S0f1Jrhowsihap8QzZioJ8',
  'email' => 'xxx',
  'password' => 'xxx',
  'remember' => 'on',
)  
[2019-08-02 00:25:38] production.DEBUG: correct user
[2019-08-02 00:25:39] production.DEBUG: RedirectIfAuthenticated handle  
[2019-08-02 00:25:39] production.DEBUG: Request array (
)  <<< EMPTY
[2019-08-02 00:25:39] production.DEBUG:
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that I overlook all the time is where the redirect route goes, and if it is within the `Auth` middleware.  If you are redirecting after authentication to a route that is outside that middleware, you'll lose the user and everything else.

Check to make sure that whatever route you send to from  `RedirectIfAuthenticated()` (the second time, #4 on your list) is within your `Auth` middleware.  Example below:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {  // here }
```

Comment: thx, I wish it had been that. I am getting crazy. I switched the PHP version to 7.2 and for a short moment I came a redirect further but then when building the view the Auth info was lost and Auth::check() returned false. It begins to seems so intermittent that I believe that it's something with the cache, although a change between file/database and cookies did neither help